# Method to rescale signals to mean length

Tags: statistics, interpolation

I have a set of signals of varying lengths. I have provided an example of the same below -

[Time Series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpHdF.png)

Their lengths vary between 186 to 202, with a mean length of 197. I am looking to rescale them to the mean length. I am looking for ideas to do the same. Perhaps a good start will be reinterpolation, but I am open to other approaches too.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean (intend)  by *rescale them to mean length*.

Comment: @poetasis For some reason, I am not able to include an image that could better explain my problem. Let's just say that I have a set of sinusoidal patterns with lengths 186 to 202. I want them all to have the same length. The reason I want to do this procedure is to perform analysis that requires signals of equal lengths.

Comment: Please edit your question to include example of what you want to achieve. My answer was base on my best understanding of your comment.

Comment: @poetasis I didn't downvote your answer :)

Comment: Understood but, if you provide examples of your target(s), perhaps I could edit my answer to get an upvote AND provide the answer you NEED.

Comment: Agreed, I will do it soon !

Comment: @poetasis I have included the image to better explain my problem.

Answer (score -1):

It  appears that they all have the same waveform and length but vary in time of occurrence so some are missing part of the front and others missing part of the back compared to the mean. I used to be in comm electronics and what we might try is

Measure the time ticks of $t_0-t_1$ and $t_2-t_1$ where $t_0$ is the start, $t_1$ is the peak, and $t_2$ is the end of the mean. Then do the same measurements for the other waves (for the $visible$ portion) and identify the $greatest$ deviations among them to find the shortest time before the peak and the shortest time after. That done, subtract, delay, omit the portion of all waves, including the mean, that extend beyond the measured time intervals $t_1-t_b$  (beginning), and $t_e-t_1$ (ending). This should bring them all in phase for analysis of what they have in common. Let me know if I'm still not getting it..